# Where is this padding/margin coming from on my website?

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass, zurb-foundation

I recently made a website for a church. I used Foundation, SASS, and Compass. I've almost got it finished up when I notice that if you size the window down I get a horizontal scroll. So I add  `overflow-x: hidden;` I thought that fixed it but when I tested it on my iPad I am still getting  roughly `20px` of padding on the right side. I then thought maybe it was from the `box-shadow` which made sense so I removed all the box shadows and its still there. Here is the link: http://www.jessefoutch.com/fumc/ any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Foundation already has its own set padding and margin for grid-columns and other grid elements. You can either change these parameters in the _settings.scss file in Foundation, or you can set the padding or margins to 0 manually and that should fix any of your issues.  I checked and didn't actually see the issue you were speaking of however, so it may no longer be affecting your site

Comment: Yes that's because I have the overflow-x hidden on the body. If you remove that style with chrome or ff then when you resize the horizontal scroll bar appears.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need to clear your cache.  I have looked at the site in Firefox, Safari, and Chrome and only saw the standard browser scroll bar when I resized.

Comment: Thanks  but it is definitely not a cache problem. I have tried it on numerous devices and browsers. You can't see it right now because of the overflow hidden on the body but if you remove that style it shows up. I will mess with it later but I was hoping it was something simple that a fresh pair of eyes might notice. If you can open it in a phone or tablet you will see. Thanks

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. I looked a bit more and discovered that you are using margins and padding combined with 100% width. I removed the "overflow:hidden: from the body, then on line 159 of app.css (.row .row) I set margin to 0 and that seemed to fix it for me.

Comment: Unfortunately I could not get it to work without messing up something else. This one is frustrating.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to your problem?

Comment: Unfortunately no I did not.